# Pass custom type as command parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, command

I have to migrate an old Delphi application to WPF with the MVVM Light framework, in my main screen I have about 50 `MenuItem`s... (no comment).

Currently, each `MenuItem` has a `RelayCommand` that executes a generic method based on a precise model:

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding ShowOrderCommand}"/>
```

and in ViewModel

```
ShowOrderCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowGridType<OrderModel>, CanShowGridType)
```

(where `OrderModel` interface is `IBaseModel`) calling this method definition:

```
ShowGridType<T>() where T : IBaseModel
```

(note: generic type must be kept because of DI resolution further in code).

I would like to remove these hundreds of lines of `RelayCommand<OrderModel, PriceModel, ...>` instantiations by a single command that can pass the type of model via a command parameter (or other) with a generic method like `ShowCommand = RelayCommand<IBaseModel>` or `RelayCommand<TModel>`.

I thought I had found the solution simply through this:

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding ShowCommand}"  CommandParameter="{x:Type models:OrderModel}"/>
ShowCommand = RelayCommand<IBaseModel>(ShowGridType);
ShowGridType<Tmodel>(Tmodel model) where Tmodel : IBaseModel
```

But when I click on my MenuItem I have a conversion error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'XXXXXX.Models.IBaseModel'
```

I have also tried to receive an 'object' instead of a `IBaseModel`, but can't find how to use this with the generic definition `ShowGridType<T>` .

Any idea that will help?

Comment: how did you set CommandParameter before changing to RelayCommand<IBaseModel>?

Comment: Not sure to understand. But the initialisation of the relaycommand is: RelayCommand<IBaseModel> EditCommand {get;set;} and in the constructor  EditCommand  = RelayCommand<IBaseModel>(ShowGridType);

Comment: what was in CommandParameter, before it became `CommandParameter="{x:Type models:OrderModel}"`? I don't think you need to change it at all

Comment: Nothing before this, because the type was hard-coded in each relaycommand instantiations in the constructor of viewmodel i.e.:ShowOrderCommand = RelayCommand(ShowGridType<OrderModel>, CanShowGridType)

Comment: @PhilSE Is the point of your question how to expose a **single** command  that calls the generic method with the concrete type of the object? This also means, just using a method with a `IBaseModel` parameter is **not possible**, because you need to access methods, fields or properties **on the concrete type**? Apart from that, you do not pass the object as command parameter, it is available as a field or property in your view model, right?

Comment: @PhilSE Another question is which container you use. Do you need the type only to resolve an instance via a container? Then there might not even be a need for a generic method.

Comment: @thatguy OMG, I've completely missunderstood the use of CommandParameter, I understand now that I send a Type object and I want to catch an Interface of my models. I'm so sorry :/
I use Unity as container and I only need the type to resolve many things that are generic like my GenericGrid<TModel> that will load views and viewmodels for the 50 models, and the start point is the MenuItem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use Unity as container and I only need the type to resolve many things [...]

If it is only about resolution, you could expose the command with `Type` as parameter.

```
public RelayCommand<Type> ShowOrderCommand { get; }
```

Create methods for the execute and can execute delegates.

```
private bool CanShowOrder(Type type)
{
   // ...replace with your code.
   return true;
}

private void ShowOrder(Type type)
{
   // Resolve type using the your container here.
   var obj= _myUnityContainer.Resolve(type);

   // ...do something with the instance.
}
```

As you can see, Unity does not only provide the generic extension methods for resolving, there are others that work with `Type`, see below. That means you do not need a generic method in your view model.

- [Documentation for *Resolve*](http://unitycontainer.org/api/Unity.IUnityContainer.html#Unity_IUnityContainer_Resolve_System_Type_System_String_Unity_Resolution_ResolverOverride___)

  ```
  object Resolve(Type type, string name, params ResolverOverride[] overrides)
  ```
- [Documentation for *UnityContainerExtensions*](http://unitycontainer.org/api/Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.html#Unity_UnityContainerExtensions_Resolve_Unity_IUnityContainer_System_Type_Unity_Resolution_ResolverOverride___)

  ```
  public static object Resolve(this IUnityContainer container, Type t, params ResolverOverride[] overrides)
  ```

Initialize the `ShowOrderCommand` command using both methods.

```
ShowOrderCommand = new RelayCommand<Type>(ShowOrder, CanShowOrder);
```

In XAML, bind the model as you did in the question as command parameter for each `MenuItem`.

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding ShowCommand}"  CommandParameter="{x:Type models:OrderModel}"/>
```

---

Now, if you really need to call your own generic method with a specific type, there are two options.

1. Check the type explicitly using an `if` or `switch` statement to call you generic `ShowGridType<T>` method.

   ```
   private void ShowOrder(Type type)
   {
      if (type == typeof(OrderModel))
         ShowGridType<OrderModel>();

      // ...check other derivatives.
   }
   ```
2. [Reflect the method and type parameter and call it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/232535/6181599). Here, you get the method info using [`GetMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=net-5.0) and use the concrete `Type` that you have as type parameter for it. Then you invoke it on `this`, because the method is defined in the containing class, and without parameters (`null`).

   ```
   private void ShowOrder(Type type)
   {
      var method = GetType().GetMethod(nameof(ShowGridType), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
      var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);

      genericMethod.Invoke(this, null);
   }
   ```

   Please be aware that you there are some pitfalls, so this is just a proof-of-concept.

Both methods involve reflection, as you need to check the runtime type. Passing an `IBaseModel` as a command parameter will not magically call a generic method with a concrete type at runtime. This also means that there is a certain overhead and errors can occur at runtime, while the code compiles just fine, so you need to be sure what you are doing and check the code carefully.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and your explanations ! It's clear for me now. I will probably do the job with reflection methods. May the tech god bless you !

Comment: this is terrible. if generics cannot be impelemented, stick to using `object` (like `ICommand ` declares).

Comment: @ASh Actually, I agree with you. However, @PhilSE does not pass an instance, he only needs the type and even if he did, what would you do with `object` if you need to operate on a concrete type? Or did I misunderstand you? How does `object` solve the problem?

Comment: "what would you do with object if you need to operate on a concrete type" - I would do a type cast. "he only needs the type" - somehow without [mcve] I'm not conviced it should be implemented that way.

Comment: @ASh Yes, a type cast, but to which type _at runtime_? The original solution of OP is exactly that, one `RelayCommand<T>` with a distinct type parameter for each model type, not even a need for a cast there, the relay command does it implicitly. The question of OP is if you only use a single command, but you need a concrete type, what would you do? I do not think there is an alternative for that specific question. Of course, you could change the design completely and in that case the example is definitely not enough.